# dropdown event handler writing in asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

What properties should I enabled in dropdown menu and how should I initiate the code in C#? I'm using Visual studio as my back end.

Comment: Every asp.net control provides several events. Which event do you want to handle? What is it that you are trying to achieve with this dropdown?

Comment: I want to place the value of the dropdown in a certain textbox, but it didn't work. – Therence 56 mins ago 
My project is when a certain value(object) selected in dropdownlist1, the drpdownlist2 will appears all the attributes that I selected in the value(object) in dropdownlist1, and I am using a web service in c# –

Answer (score 2):

ASPX:

Set the auto postback and add an event handler:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="foo" AutoPostback="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="foo_SelectedIndexChanged>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In the .CS

```
protected void foo_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e){

}
```

Comment: I want to place the value of the dropdown in a certain textbox, but it didn't work.

Comment: My project is when a certain value(object) selected in dropdownlist1, the drpdownlist2 will appears all the attributes that I selected in the value(object) in dropdownlist1, and I am using a web service in c#

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for your requirements.
1. Getting dataset value from Database.
2. Biding for the required DropDownList
3. Selecting default value for the DropDownList.

Make Sure to check autopost back property to "True"

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/400833/How-to-bind-or-populate-data-into-a-Dropdown-List

Comment: My project is when a certain value(object) selected in dropdownlist1, the drpdownlist2 will appears all the attributes that I selected in the value(object) in dropdownlist1, and I am using a web service in c#